# Archive program using 7zip dll

Tags: c++, 7zip

I'm trying to make a small archive program using 7zip dll, but I can't figure out how to use it. I don't know where the CLSID and IID are defined, what IID to use in order to be able to compress multimple files into an archive. 
My code looks something like this:

```
typedef int (_CreateObject)(const GUID clsid, const GUID iid, void *outObject);
HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("7zra.dll");
_CreateObject pfnCreate = (_CreateObject)GetProcAddress(hMod, "CreateObject");
GUID CLSID_CFormat7z = {0x23170F69, 0x40C1, 0x2790, {0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x10, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00}};
GUID IID_Coder = {0x23170F69, 0x40C1, 0x278A, {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00}};
ICompressCoder2 pCoder = NULL;
int i = pfnCreate(&CLSID_CFormat7z, &IID_Coder, (void*)&pCoder);
```

I always get a NULL pointer, even if i've tried different GUIDs. 
Can anyone help me with a simple example please?

Comment: Can't you just use the lzma sdk directly? http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: what archive formats do you need to support? Is it only zip or something more?

Comment: i need a lzma compression because it's ~30% better then zip. I can't use lzma directly because I would need to implement multiple files compression.